# 2D transform causing blurry box shadow in Chrome

Tags: css, css-transforms, antialiasing

I have a `<div>` of an unknown width (different text can be put into it) which I'm trying to position absolutely and then center using `left: 50%` and `translateX(-50%)`. This works great except that the box shadow I have applied to the `<div>` is sometimes blurry.

I suspect this is due to the fact that it does not always have exactly a whole pixel width depending on what text is inside, so when the `transform` is applied it's falling between pixels and the browser is trying to antialias it.

Check out the JSFiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/cqky6exx

Any thoughts on how I can resolve this?

Comment: you should add your code to the question so future SO users can see the issue and resolution.

Comment: Code is linked to in the JSFiddle. Should it be repeated directly in the issue itself?

Comment: generally, yes. It ensures that in the future the code/solution will be available for other SO users - you never know if jsFiddle (or whatever site) will shut down.